# Required pagination form top to bottom

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
    $('.off_onlinecourses').DataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 5,
        "lengthMenu": [ 5, 10, 15,20,25,30 ]     
    }); 
});
```

right now am using this code but i want to display list from top to bottom, I am fresher to this site and that too company also plz suggest me.TIA

Comment: question is unclear. very unclear. In fact you forgot ask question.

Comment: Have you tried `lengthMenu: [30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5]`?

Comment: Hi am doing pagination, as per my code its working  from top to bottom it showing fine but i want to display bottom to top. sorry for the inconviance.